# How to maximize the number of elements per btree node

Tags: algorithm, b-tree

I am constructing a btree from some data. Once I construct the btree (i.e. insert all the elements) I no longer insert or remove elements. However the resulting btree is not optimal in a sense that if I can have **n** maximum elements per node very frequently my nodes contain less than n elements (The problem gets worse the bigger **n** is). This is a section from my btree with several hundred elements and **n** equal to 5. The section contains the root node and several the bottom-most nodes
[image]

As you can see quite a few of the nodes have less than 5 elements. My question is:
Is there a way to "compact" the btree after its construction so that all (except maybe some of the bottom most nodes) contain exactly **n** elements. What is going to be stored in the nodes as keys will be 32bit values but I can't guarantee they will be inserted in any particular order.

Comment: I don't have time to read this paper, but can you change the way you're constructing the btree to make it compact *during* construction? http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0020019083900844

Comment: This suggests you can construct a compact btree from scratch in linear time (in the abstract at the top): http://cpsc.yale.edu/sites/default/files/files/tr167.pdf

Comment: Those papers talk about insertion of keys "in order" which I can't guarantee. I suppose I could reconstruct my btree after the first one (since I will know the order) but this will take so much memory... I will do that if there is no other way...

Comment: Where is your data coming from?

Comment: The problem is that I have more than one btrees that take keys at the same time. The keys are shared between the btrees but I can only guarantee order for the first btree. Not any of the rest because say the first key that happens to be inserted in my first btree (which will be 0) might be the 25th key in my second btree (and it will still be zero, but I will have 25 other values already there...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the classic approach for obtaining a packed btree is not feasible because the keys/records are not delivered in key order, then there are basically two options:

- offline: build a new, packed btree from scratch
- online: compact the btree in-place by using a procedure that is the opposite of a node split

Building a new btree is simpler and faster, and it can be done 'almost' in-place. The only extra space requirement consists of one page (or page buffer) for each level of the btree, to hold the right spine of the new btree under construction. The pages of the old tree can be recycled for the new tree as soon as they have been emptied.

This scheme is often called the 'pyramid' scheme or 'packing from the bottom up'. Needless to say, it requires that the btree be taken offline completely during packing, or a function that dispatches queries to the correct tree (old or new) depending on the queried key.

Online compaction employs essentially the same logic, only the particulars are a bit different since keys (records) are leeched from right neighbours and not from the input. The tree must be compacted level by level, from the bottom upwards, starting with the left-most leaf:

- pull down the separator key from the parent node
- leech keys from the right neighbour until this node is full
- push the right neighbour's new left-most key upwards as separator
- make the right neighbour your current node, rinse and repeat

Both schemes - packed building and online compaction - can leave the nodes on the right spine of the tree under-filled or even empty. If that is not desirable then it can be fixed by redistributing keys between the final two nodes of a level. This can be done by invoking the same borrowing/balancing procedure that is used in normal btree operation. Just like the packing and the compacting, this spine rebalancing must be done from the bottom up. I.e. from the right-most leaf upwards to the root.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Could you point me to some literature about the online method? I couldn't really find anything and coded something similar that goes top down using the split procedure on any children of a non saturated node (and recurring until the tree doesn't change anymore). About the offline method, the classical approach is the one described in the two papers in comments of my question?

Comment: Googling "B-tree bulk loading" should give you a lot of info about the idea behind the offline method, like [this video by Jens Dittrich](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HJgXVxsO5YU&index=1&list=LLYq4FK2x4AwjW2FxAZPydqA). The [Rosenberg/Snyder paper](http://cpsc.yale.edu/sites/default/files/files/tr167.pdf) linked by Missie contains a detailed description and pseudo code, but it hugely overcomplicates things (to the point where it isn't very helpful at all). The crucial point is that changing a btree node can have repercussions that bubble upwards in the tree, which is why you have to work

Comment: level by level from the bottom up, so that the finished pages are protected from bubbling changes and stay exactly as you packed them. The only difference between building a packed tree and general bulk loading is that you put the desired page utilisation at 100%. The core of the algorithm is this: try to append your incoming key to the right-most leaf page (after verifying that it is greater than the tree's current max key); if the right-most page is full already, add an empty page as new right-most page and try to append the key at the next higher level **in exactly the same way**.

Comment: I've never seen the online method described anywhere, probably because is a simple extension of the idea behind bulk loading and because it holds little academical interest. I coded it because I found it a simpler way of continuing to provide lookup functionality while the compaction is going on, compared to the 'old tree + new tree + dispatcher' scheme hinted at in my post. The latter is described in some papers, but mostly as a gimick for getting nice amortised complexity bounds for algorithms that require period rebuilding of the tree structure.

Comment: I accept your answer because to the best of my knowledge and according to your answer and the pointers you have given me I can not hope to do better than the described solution. Thank you.